# Why "if" statement is executed even when the condition is False?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, if-statement, boolean

Ok this might be trivial but for clarity, I am still asking it:

```
In [1]: s = "abc"

In [2]: type(s)
Out[2]: str

In [3]: if s:
   ...:     print("works")
works

In [4]: s == True
Out[4]: False
```

So a string is not equal to `True` and even then the `if` thinks that it is `True`. Explicitly checking whether `s == True` returns `False`.

```
In [6]: if not s:
   ...:     print("works")
```

So here for the `if` statement, `not s` is False! What is happening?

Comment: `if s:` checks whether `s` is a *Truthy* value - not whether it is specifically the value `True`. `s == True` checks whether it is the exact value `True` - which it isn't, it's a string (but evaluates to being *Truthy* since it is not empty).

Comment: That solves it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`if s` is analogous to `if bool(s)`, i.e. evaluating the boolean truthiness of the value. A lot more values are *truthy* than just `True`. Since the string *isn't* the value `True`, `s == True` is false.

> By default, an object is considered true unless its class defines
>   either a `__bool__()` method that returns `False` or a `__len__()`
>   method that returns zero, when called with the object. Here are most
>   of the built-in objects considered false:
>
> - constants defined to be false: `None` and `False`.
> - zero of any numeric type: `0`, `0.0`, `0j`, `Decimal(0)`, `Fraction(0, 1)`
> - empty sequences and collections: `''`, `()`, `[]`, `{}`, `set()`, `range(0)`
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing